# populate value back in nodejs registration validation

Tags: node.js

Suppose I am creating registration form in nodejs.
By get method([Registration](/users/registration)) i am loading registration form.

When clicking submit I am doing post method,

```
router.post('/register', function (req, res) {
   console.log('respond with a Register post');
   var username = req.body.username;
   var password = req.body.password;
   var password2 = req.body.password2;
   var email = req.body.email;
   var name = req.body.name;
   req.checkBody('username', 'username should not be empty').notEmpty();
   req.checkBody('password', 'password should not be empty').notEmpty();
   req.checkBody('password2', 'confirm password should not be empty').notEmpty();
   req.checkBody('password2', 'confirm password not matching to password').equals(password);
   req.checkBody('email', 'email should not be empty').notEmpty();
   req.checkBody('email', 'email is not valid').isEmail();
   req.checkBody('name', 'name should not be empty').notEmpty();
   var errors = req.validationErrors();
   if (errors) {
     res.render('register', {
        title: "Registration"
        , user: null
        , errors: errors
    });
  }
  else {//validate and do process}
});
```

When not entering all value, it is returning back it should pre populate all values back.

Please suggest what need to do?

Comment: For the form to display the data after returning back, you have to send the data to the form when returning it and in the form you have to check if any data is returned and if yes display those data in the form fields.

Comment: Suppose I am passing value like                                                                 <code>if (errors) {
     res.render('register', {
        title: "Registration"
        , username: 'username'
        , errors: errors
    });</code> how to use in register.ejs file